# How to bind Telerik Report to DataTable from a business object while keeping "design/preview" capabilities?

Tags: telerik

Assume the following problem context:

1) In our application, we have a business object with the following method:

```
public DataTable GetCars(int modelID)
```

Method is found in Cars class. This returns many cards for a given model.

2) Our dev team really wants to use the design/preview features available in the Telerik Reporting tools to design and layout the report for the results given in the DataTable.

3) We have tried to bind the DataTable mentioned above to the the report using the object data source.   The wizard seems to terminate immediately after selecting our "GetCar" method.

Do you have any suggestions regarding how you can "re-use" Business objects we have created while still keeping the advantages of the Telerik Reporting design surface?

Any tips or tricks you can offer would be welcome.

*What have we tried?*

- We know that the "design/preview"
  features work well for the
  SqlDataSource object.
- We have also reviewed the following article from Telerik

  http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/object-data-source-how-to-bind-to-data-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution...

1) Design your report using a SQL datasource against a table or view.
2) Design your Model method to produce the same schema of output as the SQL datasource.
3) When implementing the report in your web application, change the datasource to point to your object data source as described in the Telerik link above.  We would assume that your object data source is properly related to your Model method.

Comment: HOw do you change the datasource of a chart object programtically?

Comment: Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportViewer ReportViewer1 = new Telerik.ReportViewer.WebForms.ReportViewer();                                
// Creating the ObjectDataSource component:
Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();
objectDataSource.DataSource = GetData(); // returns a DataTable
// Creating a new report
ReportLib.SearchResultsReport report = new ReportLib.SearchResultsReport();
// Assigning the ObjectDataSource component to the DataSource property 
report.DataSource = objectDataSource;
ReportViewer1.Report = report;

Answer (score 0):

Well to create and run the  reports using Visual Studio or the new Desginer while binding it to a objectdatasource : All you have to do is hardcode the connection string into the class of your data method . and inside that method use the connection string.
Check my blog:
http://flying2mind.blogspot.com/2013/10/creatingrunning-telerik-reports-in.html

http://flying2mind.blogspot.com/2013/07/telerik-report-doesnt-see-fields-of.html